# php string replace function with more exact results?

Tags: php, str-replace

Is it possible to make str_replace more exact without using regex?

```
$str = str_replace("replace", "REPLACE", $str);
```

For instance, if its looking to replace the word **replace** with **REPLACE**, i don't want it to change **replaces** to **REPLACEs**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Then use preg_replace() with word boundaries

Comment: Not without regexes, or exploding an all non-word-characters, or writing a custom parser... This _is_ something regexes are good at... (`preg_replace('/\breplace\b/','REPLACE',$string);`).

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely do not want to use regex, which is a horrible idea for something like this, then you can do something that replaces "replace" with "REPLACE" and then afterword do the same thing with "REPLACEs" back to "Replaces".

```
$str = str_replace("replace", "REPLACE", $str);
$str = str_replace("REPLACEs", "replaces", $str);
```

Although then you will run into the issues of "Replaces" or "replaces", exc.

Answer (score -2):

Try it:

```
str_replace("replace ", "REPLACE");
```

Off course its will work only in this case. The best way is using regex.